# Fit text into Textarea and make it bold using ipywidgets

Tags: textarea, ipywidgets

How to fit the text into the Textarea of ipywidgets in Jupyter notebook  without scrolling and to make it bold? This should be pretty straightforward too but when I run my code I get a box that I still need to scroll and text is still plain. This is my code:

```
from ipywidgets import Layout, Textarea
from Python.display import display

ta = Textarea(value=text, decription='Description:', style=dict(font_weight='bold'), layout=Layout(height='auto', width='auto'))


display(ta)
```